# How to make sure each process uses roughly same amount of time when using multiprocessing module in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Currently I am working on an asynchronous gradient algorithm with Python multiprocessing module, the main idea is that I run multiple processes that update an array of global parameters asynchronously.  I have finished most of the framework but I got a problem that some processes seems to "get stuck" sometimes while other are still running, that causes this algorithm less effective.  So I am wondering if there are good ways to make sure that they use roughly the same amount of time?

Thanks!

Comment: There must be a reason or some reasons that your subprocesses "get stuck". Without code it's hard for other to help figuring out what's going wrong. Tell us what you did and how you did when you using the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: @PhilipTzou Thanks for your comment!  Basically in each process I run a loop that calculates gradient, and in the end of each loop it updates the global parameters.  I am not sure if the problem is in Python multiprocessing module or in Linux scheduling issue, since different processes get stuck at different time, and resumes after dozens or hundreds of seconds.  The program is run in a computer with 12-cores, and if I run 6 processes in parallel, the CPU usage could vary from 100% to 600% and I have no idea why.

Comment: @PhilipTzou BTW, sometimes it could become weird that although `htop` shows nearly 0% CPU usage in the data column, but CPU usage bar reads 100% work load.

Comment: I'm afraid there may be some locks that prevent the processes keep going. Since you mentioned the CPU usage varied from 100% to 600% but not always 600%, it seems when the process get stuck it was probably waiting for some kind of signal, for example, waiting for some kind of resources being released by another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends almost entirely on the problem you try to tackle.  If you distribute a large task to several workers and one unpredictably gets a much larger chunk than the others, you will have this situation.

There are several options to avoid it:

1. Try to estimate the effort for each chunk more precisely.  Depending on your task, this might be possible.  The chunks with the most predicted effort should be split.
2. A very common way to approach this is to split the task into lots of very small chunks, many more than workers are present.  Then feed all chunks into a queue and let your workers eat their chunks from the queue.  This way when a worker receives an easy chunk it will finish it fast and take at once the next chunk from the queue, thus not ending up idle while other workers seem to be "stuck" with their harder chunk.

A real deadlock will not be fixed of course by whatever approach.